# Rolling wheel states estimation

Tags: control-theory, estimation

This question concerns nonlinear control theory. The state estimation is an important issue since the feedback loop relies on states availability. During I read the book "Nonlinear Systems: Analysis, Stability and Control", the author explores the observability of the dynamic system.

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = f(x) + g(x) \, u \\
y = h(x)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

A famous case on dynamic systems is the rolling wheel, given below. Is it possible to find some sensor function $h(q)$ such that it is possible to reconstruct the states $q = [x, \, y, \, \theta, \, \phi, \, \omega_\theta, \, \omega_\phi]^{\intercal}$ based on its reading?

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x} & = R \, \omega_\phi \, \cos{\theta} \\
\dot{y} & = R \, \omega_\phi \, \sin{\theta} \\
\dot{\theta} & = \omega_\theta \\
\dot{\phi} & = \omega_\phi \\
\dot{\omega}_\theta & = a_\theta \\
\dot{\omega}_\phi & = a_\phi
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I really think it is a relevant research problem to solve, there is very little material on even famous repositories.

Thank you

Comment: Yes thats easy: $h(q) = q$. But that is most likely not what you are looking for. You should add which states are not available for $h$, because if I can pick any $h$ I just would let it measure all states.

Comment: Yes, this is the easy case. But it is uninteresting, isn't it?! I would say $\theta$ and $\phi$ are available. For constructive reasons, I am not sure if both angular position and speed may be measured.

Comment: I assume that the last equations should be $\dot{\omega}_\phi = a_\phi$, so $\omega_\phi$ instead of $\omega_\theta$?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto With the second equation of your dynamic system, shouldn't your $y$ should be $\dot{y}$ so it's then $\dot{y} = h(x)$?

Comment: I corrected the term $\dot{\omega}_{\theta}$ to $\dot{\omega}_{\phi}$ as @Kwin remarked. The first system of equations represent a generic case of dynamic system. The second represent a specific case. They do not share the same symbolic set of variables.

Comment: $a_{\theta}$ and $a_{\phi}$ are control inputs?

Comment: They are the acceleration input.

Comment: It does not seem to exist under-observed h(x) which make the system observable rather than disposal of all states. If one further derivate the states  $\theta$ and $\phi$, the variables $\omega_\theta$ and $\omega_\phi$ provide, in total, 4 variables. The remaining two comes from x and y, the zero dynamics. But if a system has a zero dynamics, it is unobserved by the output

Comment: I think the problem is that $x, y$ are not used in the RHS of the differential equations. Therefore, creating a model of the system won't help because there is no way to correct the open loop integration of $\dot{x}$, $\dot{y}$ even if you measure all of the remaining states. You can also see this at the observability matrix of the linearized system, which has at best rank 4.

Comment: @SampleTime the same holds for $\phi$, so at least $x$, $y$ and $\phi$ need to be able to be recovered from $h(q)$.

Comment: If one measures $\phi$, $\theta$ and $\omega_\phi$, than $x$ and $y$ comes from its integration. However, I think one must know the initial conditions for both x and y (May be zero), one must design an observer to obtain both.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Any noise in the measurements or inputs will cause such estimates to drift. Even if initial conditions are known, because $x$ and $y$ are not observable if they are not directly measured.